# Display certain data in output from call back (jquery solution needed)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using a html web form to pass input fields to a php file using an AJax, the php file processes the data and returns data back. The data comes back as raw text but does have structure to it. However, alot of it i prefer not to display.

How can I manipulate data to only show certain information.

For example, data returned may look like this:

[CN] => www.domain.com

[O] => ACME INC

Usually, the information returned is formatted like the above. Is there a way for me to do a search for, say [CN] and return the rest of the data om that same line excluding the characters =>

I should end up with only www.domain.com

-- Sample of Ajax call --

```
$.ajax({
 url: 'test.php',
 success: function(response) {
 $('result').html(response);
```

Comment: Do you want to search for the www.domain.com in javascript or php?

Comment: @Black-Hole, php would probably be ideal as then i can control it from the source. But would mind seeing how bothe solutions would work.

Comment: @Black-Hole - after some thought my preference would be javascript/jquery since thats where the data is ultimately going. The php is a script file that will generate the information only and messing around with that might be more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it in JavaScript would be using a regular expression

```js
var ajaxResponse = "\r\n[CN] => www.domain.com\r\n\r\n[O] => ACME INC\r\n";
var regexParser = /^\[CN]\s*=>\s*(.*)$/m;
var parseResult = regexParser.exec(ajaxResponse);
alert(parseResult[1]);
```

Comment: Thx for ur assistance but not sure its working right.. See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9csja9bx/ it should only be returning www.domain.com (of course this is not a fixed domain so thats why i want to call it by [CN]

Comment: It is only returning "www.domain.com". What you see in the alert is the result of the regex. You see the full text in the Result pane on jsfiddle because you put it in the HTML panel. I am simulating the return from your AJAX call in the first variable in my code snippet. I'll update the snippet to make it a little clearer.

Comment: Sorry, i tried it again and i do see the window alert with the correct output. I also updated my post to show the ajax call sample and response but how do i go about adding the whole returned data as a variable?

Comment: The `response` variable in your code is equivalent to `ajaxResponse` in my code and the `html` function in your code is equivalent to the `alert` in my code.

Comment: Got it. Last question hopefully.. Just thinking out load - what will happen if in the response there is multiple instances of [CN] and on seperate lines? Will your code return both or reference the first or last im the response data?

Comment: Just tried it in fiddle. It returns the first match. Just curious can it return both?

Comment: As currently written it just returns the first. However, you can add the `g` option to the regex and get both of them. That will require iterating through the parse results, so you'll need to study the JavaScript regular expression object to see how to do that. In addition to jsfiddle for JavaScript, here is a good tool to test regular expressions: https://regex101.com/r/xE6pM3/1

Comment: That is very helpful. Thanks for your patience and assistance

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it in php:

```
<?php
$data =
    "[CN] => www.domain.com
    [O] => ACME INC";

$lines = explode("\r\n",$data);
foreach ($lines as $line ){
    $parts = explode(" => ",$line);
    if($parts[0]=="[CN]")
        echo $parts[1];
}

?>
```

And Javascript:

```
<script>
    var data ="[CN] => www.domain.com\r\n"+
        "[O] => ACME INC";

    var lines = data.split("\n");

    for(var i=0;i<lines.length;i++){
        var parts = lines[i].split(" => ");
        if(parts[0]=="[CN]")
            alert(parts[1]);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. Ill definetly explore this solution as well but will take more time to factor in to the scripts. I will wait for your jscript solution

Comment: I updated my post with the Ajax call. Your code seems to work in jsfiddle but i just want to make sure i can use this with my ajax success call. As mentioned there will be a large amount of data returned so i imagine i would need to set the entire response. Your variable only factors in two lines, i would need the entire response as the variable.

Comment: @user3436467 It doesn't focus on two lines, see for statement "lines.length"

Comment: This isna great solution that works well. Thx very much!